# EF concurrency causing problems with a trigger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

In my SQL table (2008), I have a timestamp column called Timestamp.

In my .Net project, I have a POCO class with a property

```
public byte[] Timestamp {get; set;}
```

In my configuration code, I have the following:

```
Property(p => p.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();
```

Now, if I open two edit screens make a change in one and save it (save is accepted), then make a change in the second and save it (save is rejected with DbUpdateConcurrencyException).

One thing that I find odd is that SQL Profiler shows an update request being sent to the SQL database even when I receive the concurrency exception.  The update is not committed on the database but it is sent.  Is that normal?  I kind of expected EF to check that ahead of time and not even send the request.

Lastly, if I enable the trigger on this table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_person_log_changes]
   ON  [dbo].[Person]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @auditBody XML
DECLARE @actionType char(1)
DECLARE @username nvarchar(100)

if not exists(select * from deleted)
    Begin
        SET @actionType = 'I'
        SET @username = (select Case 
                                    When lastchangedby is null or lastchangedby = '' then Suser_name()
                                    Else lastchangedby
                                End  
                         from inserted)
    End
else if not exists(select * from inserted)
    Begin
        SET @actionType = 'D'
        SET @username = Suser_name()
    End
else
    Begin
        SET @actionType = 'U'
        SET @username = (select distinct Case 
                                    When lastchangedby is null or lastchangedby = '' then Suser_name()
                                    Else lastchangedby
                                End  
                         from inserted)
    End

If @actionType = 'I'
    Set @auditBody = (select 'Person' as "@tableName",  'True' as "@synch",
      (select * from inserted for xml path('DataItem'), type, binary base64)
      for xml path('Root'))
Else
    SET @auditBody = (select 'Person' as "@tableName", 'True' as "@synch",
      (select * from deleted for xml path('DataItem'), type, binary base64)
      for xml path('Root'))

insert into [dbo].[AuditLog]
           ([Action]
           ,[ActionDate]
           ,[ActionUser]
           ,[AuditData]
           )
    values (
           @actionType
           ,getdate()
           ,@username
           ,@auditBody)
END
```

Now when I try to save the second edit, I no longer get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException, I get an error stating that ActionUser can't be null.  Once again, I think my trigger is being executed because EF is allowing the update to go through even though there is a conflict.

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

**NOTE**

This is an MVC project.  In my Edit POST controller, I'm receiving a DTO object that contains all the form properties (one of which is Timestamp -- a hidden field on my edit form).  I'm loading the edited person from the datacontext and mapping the edited properties from the DTO object into the Domain object returned from the datacontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do optimistic concurrency right is doing the version check and being 100% sure that nothing changes until the actual update is done. The most convenient way to do this is incorporate the version check in the `UPDATE` statement, so that's what EF does. So it does send an update statement, which looks like

```sql
UPDATE table SET columnA = value
WHERE rowversion = xxxx
```

However, when the statement does not find the row with the `rowversion` it had in memory it returns a different number of affected rows than expected and the exception is throw. **And the transaction is rolled back**. So yes, you see a statement in SQL Profiler, but it is never committed.

The trigger runs as part of the update statement, i.e. before EF is reported back about the update command. Apparently, `@username` doesn't get a value in the process, so this throws a SQL exception that spoils the update party before any concurrency conflict is noticed.

Comment: Thanks for that.  A friend of mine (thanks Jack) gave me a solution.  He told me to check @@ROWCOUNT = 0 in my Trigger.  If that is true, then I just return and don't do any of the logic for adding to the audit log.

Comment: OK, could save some performance, but the addition to the log should be rolled back as well as far as I get it.

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer.  There is no addition to the log to roll back.  Because the update did not update any rows (due to the where clause) @@ROWCOUNT in the trigger is 0 ... therefore, I exit out of the trigger and don't add anything to the audit log ... nothing to rollback!